# convert the HTML tags to the HTML formatted display

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, impromptu

i have some HTML content in a database, and using impromptu as a light box to display some html content. 
where want it to be like

***This is a Sample Text***

but it displays as

```
<em><strong><span style="color: #ff6600;">This is a Sample Text</span></strong></em>
```

is there a way to convert the tagged text to the formatted text?

Comment: You need to show more code.

Answer (score 1):

[RTM](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/#Methods), you can do this by using the html: method

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just write

```
$.prompt("<em><strong><span style='color: #ff6600;'>This is a Sample Text</span></strong></em>");
```

Reference: http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/

It is possible though that the HTML content in the database is converted to HTML characters references. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: it does not state that anywhere on the site, it states that you need to use the html option.

Comment: Quote: 'The message can either be an html string, or an object of "states"'. A state has a html option yes, but the message doesn't need to exist of states.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that doesn't depend on jQuery, which will convert it exactly like you are wanting:

```
function str_to_html(text)
{
    var a = document.createElement('div');
    a.innerHTML = text;
    return a.textContent;
}

// This function will convert '&lt;sometag&gt;' to '<sometag>', causing the markup
// to be interpreted properly by the browser for your purpose.
```